# How to add two rows in a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here I am trying to add multiple rows in one cell, but fail.

Please help me in coding and give me idea if there is other control in which we can do so.

```
string[] innerrow1 = new string[] { "50", "60", "70" };
string[] innerrow2 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, innerrow2);

object[] row = new object[] { "1", innerrow1, "1000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new object[] { "2", innerrow2, "2000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code is adding the type of innerrow to the second column. What you want is that all strings are put in the second column?

Comment: Is the second column meant to be a drop down?

Comment: Please explain what results you are seeing and what you are trying to get them to be. It seems like you want rows within rows, that cannot be done. Or are you just trying to get the text "50,60,70" to appear in the second column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all tring in a single cell simpli change your code as below

```
    string innerrow1 = "50 60 70";
    string innerrow2 = "a b c";
```

If you want a Combobox

```
    string[] innerrow1 = new string[] { "50", "60", "70" };
    string[] innerrow2 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    Col1.HeaderText = "Product ID";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Col1);

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Col2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    Col2.HeaderText = "Product Name";
    Col2.Name = "Product Name";
    Col2.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
    Col2.Items.Add(innerrow1[0]);
    Col2.Items.Add(innerrow1[1]);
    Col2.Items.Add(innerrow1[2]);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Col2);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    Col3.HeaderText = "Product Price";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Col3);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", innerrow1[0], "1000" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", innerrow1[1], "2000" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", innerrow1[2], "3000" });
```

If you want different drop down for each row

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string[] innerrow1 = new string[] { "50", "60", "70" };
    string[] innerrow2 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    Col1.HeaderText = "Product ID";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Col1);

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Col2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    Col2.HeaderText = "Product Name";
    Col2.Name = "Product Name";
    Col2.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
    Col2.Items.Add(innerrow1[0]);
    Col2.Items.Add(innerrow1[1]);
    Col2.Items.Add(innerrow1[2]);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Col2);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    Col3.HeaderText = "Product Price";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Col3);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", innerrow1[0], "1000" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", innerrow2[0], "2000" });

    setCellComboBoxItems(dataGridView1, 0, 1, innerrow1);
    setCellComboBoxItems(dataGridView1, 1, 1, innerrow2);

}

private void setCellComboBoxItems(DataGridView dataGrid, int rowIndex, int colIndex, object[] itemsToAdd)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcbc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];
    // You might pass a boolean to determine whether to clear or not.
    dgvcbc.Items.Clear();
    foreach (object itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
    {
        dgvcbc.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```